# Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial chapter 11 & 12: multiple erros and mails not being send

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, forgot-password

I'm currently at step 12 with the rails tutorial and am having problems with sending the account activation emails and visiting certain pages( i get errors)

When requesting a password reset I get the following error

```
NameError in PasswordResetsController#create

uninitialized constant User::FILL_IN

Extracted source (around line #62):

  def create_reset_digest
    self.reset_token = User.new_token

    (the code below is highlighted red)

    update_columns(reset_digest:  FILL_IN, reset_sent_at: FILL_IN)

  end

  # Sends password reset email.
```

source being:

```
app/models/user.rb:62:in `create_reset_digest'
app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb:12:in `create'
```

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token
  before_save   :downcase_email
  before_create :create_activation_digest
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true

  # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end


  # Returns a random token.
  def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  # Remembers a user in the database for use in persistent sessions.
  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end

  # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(remember_token)
    return false if remember_digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
  end

  # Forgets a user.
  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end

  def authenticated?(attribute, token)
    digest = send("#{attribute}_digest")
    return false if digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
  end

  # Activates an account.
  def activate
    update_columns(activated: FILL_IN, activated_at: FILL_IN)
  end

  # Sends activation email.
  def send_activation_email
    UserMailer.account_activation(self).deliver_now
  end

  # Sets the password reset attributes.
  def create_reset_digest
    self.reset_token = User.new_token
    update_columns(reset_digest:  FILL_IN, reset_sent_at: FILL_IN)
  end

  # Sends password reset email.
  def send_password_reset_email
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver_now
  end

    # Returns true if a password reset has expired.
  def password_reset_expired?
    reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
  end

  private

    # Converts email to all lower-case.
    def downcase_email
      self.email = email.downcase
    end

    # Creates and assigns the activation token and digest.
    def create_activation_digest
      self.activation_token  = User.new_token
      self.activation_digest = User.digest(activation_token)
    end
end
```

**app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb**

```
class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :get_user,         only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :valid_user,       only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :check_expiration, only: [:edit, :update]    # Case (1)

  def new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:password_reset][:email].downcase)
    if @user
      @user.create_reset_digest
      @user.send_password_reset_email
      flash[:info] = "Email sent with password reset instructions"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "Email address not found"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if params[:user][:password].empty?
      @user.errors.add(:password, "can't be empty")
      render 'edit'
    elsif @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      log_in @user
      @user.update_attribute(:reset_digest, nil)
      flash[:success] = "Password has been reset."
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
    end

    # Before filters

    def get_user
      @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    end

    # Confirms a valid user.
    def valid_user
      unless (@user && @user.activated? &&
              @user.authenticated?(:reset, params[:id]))
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    end

    # Checks expiration of reset token.
    def check_expiration
      if @user.password_reset_expired?
        flash[:danger] = "Password reset has expired."
        redirect_to new_password_reset_url
      end
    end
end
```

When i try to view a user i get the following error

```
NameError in UsersController#show
uninitialized constant UsersController::FILL_IN

Extracted source (around line #12):

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    (the code below being red)

    redirect_to root_url and return unless FILL_IN

  end

  def new
```

source being :

```
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:12:in `show'
```

**app/controllers/users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy

  def index
    @users = User.where(activated: FILL_IN).paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to root_url and return unless FILL_IN
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
            flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

   def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User deleted"
    redirect_to users_url
  end

    # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(attribute, token)
    digest = send("#{attribute}_digest")
    return false if digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :company, :phone, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end

# Confirms a logged-in user.
    def logged_in_user
      unless logged_in?
             store_location
        flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
        redirect_to login_url
      end
    end

    # Confirms the correct user.
    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless @user == current_user
    end

        def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end

end
```

I've been at this for over a day searching for answers on different posts and retracing and redoing my steps, but I've got no clue what I've done wrong.

I can't visit the user pages and when I submit forget password i get errors

Comment: Where it says FILL_IN you are supposed to put in code there.  He left those empty as part of the exercises, so you are supposed to figure out what goes in there and then write the code.

Comment: @RockwellRice I'm really new to Ruby, and i can't find a mentioning on the tutorial of what i should fill in, i thought it would get that parameter by it self?

Comment: No it will not happen by itself, he is basically saying that part of the exercise is to figure out what code goes in there.  I would re-read that chapter and see if you can understand it well enough to fill that in.  That is kind of the point of that.  For instance, in that show method you would want to redirect back to the root url unless what condition was met?  Once you know that answer then figure out how to check for that with code.  It is not something you have not gone over at that point so it is not something new you have to figure out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def index
  @users = User. where(activated: true) . paginate(page: params[:page] )
end

def show
  @user = User. find(params[:id] )
  redirect_to root_url and return unless true
end

def activate
    update_columns(activated: true, activated_at: Time.zone.now)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
update_columns(reset_digest:  User.digest(reset_token), reset_sent_at: Time.zone.now)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def index
    @users = User.where(activated: true).paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to root_url and return unless @user.activated?
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
```

Comment: Consider adding a short explanation on what this code does to your answer